# Las migrations de Laravel no reflejan el esquema actual de la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, base-de-datos

Estoy trabajando con un app en Laravel/MySQL que no tiene todas sus tablas definidas a través de las migraciones, porque en un momento dejaron de usar las migraciones e hicieron cambios directamente tocando la base de datos. Esto hace que si yo ejecuto un `php artisan migrate` no tome el esquema actual de la DB. Mi pregunta es si tengo alguna manera de volver a usar migraciones desde la estructura actual de la DB. Si hay algún procedimiento que me actualice las migraciones incluyendo aquellos campos que fueron adicionados directamente en la tabla en la base de datos.

Comment: No veo por qué no se podría hacer esto, ¿Qué intentas hacer? ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué problemas hay?

Answer (score 1):

No hay ninguna manera automática, tendrás que crear las migraciones manualmente de las tablas nuevas o editar las migraciones antiguas con las relaciones y campos nuevos. (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations) Aun a si las migraciones no se utilizan para nada más que al principio para crear la base de datos, no sé yo si te vale la pena actualizarlas, sería mejor tener un buen esquema ERR de como esta estructurada la base de datos para hacer y deshacer cambios.